# Getting a shell on a shell-less account?

Tags: centos, bash, sudo

I’m managing a CentOS 4.7 server with several for security reasons shell-less user accounts. But sometimes I need a user-shell for installations anyway.
What is the best way to get a login shell? Just now I use

```
sudo –u <user> bash –rcfile /home/<user>/.bash_profile
```

But this is not perfect. A lot of the environment variables are not intitialized.

Erich

Comment: A very quick suggestion: you might want to be specific about the environment variables you're finding aren't set to your liking.

Comment: Especially HISTFILE and HOME were not set which annoyed me most. Anyway, esm provided the command I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo -u <user> -H -- bash -l
```

The sudo argument "-H" will set the home directory properly, and the "-l" option to bash will indicate that this is a login shell. You might also experiment with adding the bash argument "-p".